# Flutter - how to localize the setState()?

Tags: flutter

From the official docs we can read:

> When setState() is called on a State, all descendent widgets rebuild.
> Therefore, localize the setState() call to the part of the subtree
> whose UI actually needs to change. Avoid calling setState() high up in
> the tree if the change is contained to a small part of the tree.

So what exactly the "localize the setState()" means? How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

It means that it's better to call setState() on the only widget that needs to update.
Let's see an example:

```
Column(
  children:[
    FooWidget() //which you wanna update(rebuild)
    AnotherWidget() //wich you don't want to rebuild
  ],
)
```

If you wrap the whole of this column with a stateful widget, any time you use setState(), both `FooWidget()` and `AnotherWidget()` will rebuild and of course it's not what flutter and you want!
It's a wasting of hardware usage for no needed update.

So, localizing setState() means that you make the `FooWidget()` stateful and call setState() on 'FooWidget()' instead of the whole of the column.

Comment: what if i change a variable in the root widget, but the variable is only used in FooWidget(). Is there a way to rebuild only FooWidget()?

Comment: If that variable is only used in `FooWidget()`, you shouldn't define it in the root. Otherwise, you should define a callback in that widget and update the value of that variable by that callback. And also use setState in that callback in `FooWidget()`

Comment: how do i do it? I create a callback and pass it into FooWidget(callback) and then I can call something like callback.update() outside of FooWidget(), is that so?

Comment: First of all, tell me where you want to update the value of that var? in `FooWidget()` or in the parent?